# ios swift search bar color change

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change the gray area (rectangle area) color of the search bar to a different color (orange). Ive tried using searchBar.barTintColor = but that is only changing the color of the cancel button and not the gray area. 
**EDIT**

```
class usersVC: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

// declare searchBar
var searchBar = UISearchBar()


// default function 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // implement search bar
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - 30
    let searchItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchItem
}
```

Comment: Please try with `searchBar.tintColor = `

Comment: this gives me the same results as .barTintColor

Answer (score 2):

Try this again.

[image]

I created this effect by loading a simple image with an orange background, seen below.

```
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "orange")
```

Background image:

[image]

EDIT 1

Based on your recent comment, I tested this with a programatically created searchbar and it works as well.

[image]

Comment: type UIBarStyle has no member Orange

Comment: and when i tried that using .black it changes the color inside the search box i want to be able to change the color around the search box

Comment: I updated the answer which is working in Swift 2.2. Included asset as well to assist OP.

Comment: does it matter if i created my searchbar programatically

Comment: No, I just updated the answer to show a working bar with programatically created search bar. Just to verify, do you have the right name for the color file? If you download the one I have & add it to XCode, it will not be match the name in the code I put up.

Comment: yes i named it orange and then tried and it didnt work, so i tried writing "orange.png" as well and it didnt work either

Comment: What version of XCode do you have?

Comment: Same as me. Can you update your question with the code you are using similar to what I have posted?